# This proof claims that AEKF is concyclic because of angles in the same segment, except that the angles in the diagram are in opposite segments

Tags: solution-verification, euclidean-geometry

Here's something I found in a pdf about Euclidean Geometry:

> *Lemma.* Triangle $ABC$ with points $D$, $E$, $F$ on lines $BC$, $CA$, $AB$ respectively have $(AEF)$, $(BFD)$, $(CDE)$ concurrent at a point.

Context: $(AEF)$ is a circle that passes through points $A$, $E$, $F$. I'm not sure whether this notation is commonly used or not.

Here's a diagram (hastily drawn on GeoGebra) to show this. Ignore J, I, K, G
[image: Miquel Point]

The proof provided in the pdf is as follows (it uses directed angles)

> Let $L$ be this intersection.
> $\angle FLD=\angle FBD=\angle ABC$
> $\angle DLE=\angle DCE=\angle BCA$
> Since $0=\angle DLE+\angle ELF+\angle FLD=\angle ABC+\angle BCA+\angle CAB$,
> $\angle ELF=\angle CAB$
> So $AELF$ is concyclic. QED

Here's my problem: **I don't think that $\angle ELF=\angle CAB$ is true.** It would be true if they were angles in the same segment, but based on the diagram above, it seems that they are angles in the opposite segment. Shouldn't $\angle ELF= 180 ° - \angle CAB$ be the relationship that should be shown? In the case of directed angles (context: author considers angles modulo $180°$), shouldn't $\angle ELF= - \angle CAB$ be shown?

Comment: Edit: Found out that I had a misunderstanding about directed angles. After reading the motivation behind defining directed angles to remove configuration errors, I understand the author's proof. ELF = CAB applies to both angles in the same segment and angles in the opposite segment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Found out that I had a misunderstanding about directed angles. After reading the motivation behind defining directed angles to remove configuration errors, I understand the author's proof. $ELF = CAB$ applies to both angles in the same segment and angles in the opposite segment.